# Google Maps renders with blurry tiles

Tags: google-maps

We have developed a Droid Tablet GPS App which utilizes Google Maps.  One of our users reports that sometimes the maps show partially blurry:

[image]

They are using a wireless connection.  And this is an application used in a vehicle (i.e. so the maps update and pan as user moves around).

Does this happen because Google first renders low resolution images and then updates them with high res images?  And in this case the connection could have been lost before the high resolution images loaded?

Is there any way to prevent this?

NOTE: please before someone tags this as "Not programming related" listen to me.  I am posting here because on the relevant Google Groups the moderator is encouraging people to post to StackOver flow using this tag.  ([Read More](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/MppSAw8qs5Y)).

Comment: Just because Google is encouraging technical questions on StackOverflow doesn't make all questions on topic.  You haven't posted any code, how can it be programming related? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using Google Maps, not programming.

Comment: I understand..  But I was unsuccessful finding an explanation for the blurriness doing web searches everywhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, AFAIK there's no way to prevent this on the client side. It's just how Google Maps works.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to actually answer the question!